# DBNull Exception Problems

Tags: c#, sql

I am having an issue with my code today. Whenever I use this method to add a Product to my local DB, it throws an exception that reads "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types". After doing some research, I believe my issue resides with the insertCmd parameters in the AddProduct method, but I cannot seem to figure out exactly what is causing it. The program that I have created still functions correctly (it adds the product and can then be selected successfully), however it just seems to keep throwing this exception when I add the product.

Can anyone provide any insight as to where the issue might lie within my code? If you need any more information, please do not hesitate to ask. Thank you for your time and help.

```
public static bool AddProduct(Product product)
{
SqlConnection connect = MMABooksDB.GetConnection();
string insert = "INSERT Products " + "(ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice) " + "VALUES (@code, @description, @price)";
SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insert, connect);
insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", product.code);
insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", product.description);
insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", product.price);
     try
        {
            connect.Open();
            insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string selectStatement =
                "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Products') FROM Products";
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connect);
            int ProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
         return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
}
```

And here is the product class

```
public class Product
{
    public string code;
    public string description;
    public decimal price;

    public Product() { }

    public Product(string code, string description, decimal price)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public string Code
    {
        get
        {
            return code;
        }
        set
        {
            code = value;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }

    public string GetDisplayText()
    {
        return code + ", " + price.ToString("c") + ", " + description;
    }

    public string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return code + sep + price.ToString("c") + sep + description;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug your code, what line does the exception occur on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ProductCode;  //declare variable
object dbProductID = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar(); //get the result into object
if(dbProductID !=null || dbProductID != DBNull.Value) //check if it is null
   ProductCode = 0; //assign some default value here if it has no productid
else
   ProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(dbProductID);//if its has productid cast it into int
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This solved the issue. Now I have a new problem to figure out! Gotta love programming... lol

Answer (score 0):

if the product is getting added I would assume the cannot convert is coming from `int ProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());`  I would add a check to see if that scaler is returning null.